# Downloaded CSV file - issue with UTF-8-BOM format

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, character-encoding, python-3.8

I have code that downloads a CSV file from bitbucket.
After the download the file became a list of strings (list of all rows).
The issue is when the file was UTF-8-BOM format it added chars in the beginning and then after when trying to read the CSV file it failed.
How can I encode it after download?

This is the code:

```
fld = self._download(csv_url)
converted = parser.parse(fld)

def parse(self, f: io.StringIO):
    for row in csv.reader(f):  # ---- **failed here**.
        if not row:
            continue

def _download(self, url: str):
    response = self.authenticator.download(url)
    return response.text.splitlines()
```

Comment: Define "failed".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Reading and writing csv files with utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085319/python-reading-and-writing-csv-files-with-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Don't do that, instead specify the encoding *when you open the file*. If there is still garbage then we need an example of the actual data in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If `parse` is accepting a `StringIO` instance, that suggests that the downloaded bytes have already been decoded, possibly in the `_download` method?

Comment: When you are reading, you want to _decode,_ not encode.

Comment: So the file doesn't "become" a list of lines; you do it when you call `splitlines()`. Probably remove the BOM from `response.text` before calling `splitlines()`.

Comment: And probably [edit] your question to show the actually relevant code in the question itself. Comments are ephemeral and your question should be self-contained.

Comment: remove u mean by encode?

Comment: `_download` returns a list, `parse` expects a `StringIO`…!?

Answer (score 1):

If the HTTP request returns data with a BOM and you don't want it, remove it.

```
def _download(self, url: str):
    response = self.authenticator.download(url)
    return response.text.lstrip('\ufeff').splitlines()
    #                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`str.lstrip()` is robust in the sense that it simply returns the whole string if it doesn't start with a BOM.

Comment: i needed to use `content = content.lstrip('\ufeff')` so it depends on your BOM

Comment: My bad, the lack of a `u` between the backslash and the `feff` was a typo in my original answer; fixed now.

Comment: My bad, the lack of a `u` between the backslash and the `feff` was a typo in my original answer; fixed now.